# Xamarin Forms scroll view cuts content half

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, scrollview

When I scroll down, my content does not scrolled till bottom. The content is cutted half. How can I handle this?

```
 <ScrollView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <StackLayout>

            <!--FirstPage-->
            <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Image Source="mapa.png" Aspect="Fill" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"/>

            /// content ///

            </AbsoluteLayout>


            <!--SecondPage-->

            <AbsoluteLayout  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <Image Source="mapa.png" Aspect="Fill" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"/>

            /// content ///

            </AbsoluteLayout>

        </StackLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Not sure what is the contents but possible your “content” in the Absolute layout overlay your image in the same layout?

Comment: Both of Absolute Layouts work properly in separete pages but when I put them in StackLayout with ScrollView, ScrollView does not show whole second Absolute Layout.

Comment: Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61381531/xamarin-lower-half-of-view-cut-off