# Xamarin - lower half of view cut off

Tags: xaml, xamarin, view, cut

Some times when loading a View, it does not fully load on Iphone.. see the screenshot.. (Images are blurred on purpose..) At least, it does not load with proper dimensions. it is usually fixed by rotating the phone to landscape and back.. is there a way to avoid this?

here is my view:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:GalShare.ViewModel"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
             xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:RedCorners.Forms;assembly=RedCorners.Forms"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="GalShare.Views.Gallery">

    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <Grid Padding="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Back" x:Name="Backbutton" Clicked="Backbutton_Clicked"></Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="Ph. contact info" x:Name="PhInfo" Clicked="PhInfo_Clicked"></Button>
        </Grid>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>

    <ContentPage.Content>
    <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
                <ContentView x:Name="Messagecontainer" Padding="5">
                    <forms:Frame2 CornerRadius="8"  
                               HasShadow="True"
                               ShadowRadius="8"    
                               ShadowColor="Black"
                               Padding="5"                               
                               BackgroundColor="LightGray">

                        <Label x:Name="Messagefield"></Label>
                    </forms:Frame2>
                </ContentView>
                <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Galleries}" Margin="0" x:Name="MyCollection" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="CollectionView_SelectionChanged">
                    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"                                 
                                Span="2" />

                    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentView Padding="8">
                                <forms:Frame2 CornerRadius="15"  
                                       HasShadow="True"
                                       ShadowRadius="5"   
                                       HeightRequest="190"
                                       BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                                       Padding="1">
                                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" Padding="2">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <ffimageloading:CachedImage Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="myImage" Source="{Binding ThumbUrl}" Aspect="AspectFit" CacheDuration="1" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" DownsampleToViewSize="False"></ffimageloading:CachedImage>
                                            <StackLayout Padding="0"  Margin="0"  Spacing="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                                                <StackLayout Spacing="0" Margin="0" Padding="5,0,5,0">
                                                    <ImageButton HorizontalOptions="Center" Padding="0" WidthRequest="28" Aspect="AspectFit" HeightRequest="28" Margin="0" Source="{Binding likeImg}" x:Name="Favoriteimage" Clicked="LikeButton_Clicked" ></ImageButton>
                                                 <!--   <Button CharacterSpacing="0"  HorizontalOptions="Center" Padding="0" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="28" Margin="0" Text="Like" x:Name="Favoriteimage" Clicked="Button_Clicked" ></Button>-->
                                                </StackLayout>
                                                    <Label x:Name="Picname" Text="{Binding ImageName}" IsVisible="{Binding showname}" FontSize="Micro" VerticalOptions="End" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" ></Label>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </forms:Frame2>
                            </ContentView>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding isBusy}" x:Name="LoadingLayout" Padding="12"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,-1,-1">
                <ActivityIndicator IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" 
                               IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" />
                <Label Text="Loading gallery..." IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </AbsoluteLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you used **AbsoluteLayout** as root layout of the ContentPage . If you want to put the **ActivityIndicator** on the **CollectionView** , you could use Grid and put them in the same cell .

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <StackLayout  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Red"  x:Name="LoadingLayout" Padding="12">

           //...
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" IsVisible="{Binding isBusy}" x:Name="LoadingLayout" Padding="12" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <ActivityIndicator IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" 
                               IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" />
                <Label Text="Loading gallery..." IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black"/>
        </StackLayout>

</Grid>
```

If the problem still exists, you could share your sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: thank you for your answer.. so i should replace the absolute layout with a grid? I try it right away

Comment: that fixed it! thank you! could you please explain what the problem with absolute layout is? why is it creating this problem?

Comment: I just noticed that after replacing absolutelayout with grid, the event selectionchanged is not fired anymore in my collectionview.. basically I cannot click on the images anymore

Comment: You could share your sample and I will have a check .Or you could create a new thread with more details .

Comment: You need to set the size of  second stacklayout (like 200*300). Otherwise the stacklayout will cover the whole screen .You could set the background color of it to check .

Comment: I understand the problem, but it hink it will be difficult to fix.. even if I simply make it smaller, there will still be this smaller portion that is not clickable..

Comment: You could install some plugin of `ActivityIndicator` from nuget :)